# Unable to send email using sendgrid with Laravel 5.4 and found the error

Tags: laravel, sendgrid

I am new to sendgrid, and want to integrate sendgrid with Laravel. Here I tried as
- Added below code in app\Mail\SendgridEmail.php

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendgridEmail extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $data;

public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}

public function build()
{
    $address = 'demotest@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'This is a demo!';
    $name = 'Sam';

    return $this->view('emails.templateUserRegister')
                ->from($address, $name)                    
                ->subject($subject)
                ->with([ 'message' => $this->data['message'] ]);

}
}
```

- Created template file views/emails/templateUserRegister.blade.php as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Bowoot Email</h2>
    <p>{{ $message }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

- Added below code to controller

```
use App\Mail\SendgridEmail; // on top of class

public function sendemail()
{       
    $data = array('message' => 'This is a SendgridEmail test!');

    Mail::to('user@gmail.com')->send(new SendgridEmail($data));
}
```

and when I run the code I found the error message as below

> (2/2) ErrorException
>   htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bowoot\resources\views\emails\templateUserRegister.blade.php)
>   in helpers.php (line 547)

I am unable to understand what the issue is. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the information provided is accurate, you are returning a view `emails.templateUserRegister` and it should be `email.templateUserRegister`. (Notice the s)
The reason I'm saying this is because this is your view path.

> views/email/templateUserRegister.blade.php

And it definitely doesn't have an 's'.

**Edit**

Instead of doing this:

```
return $this->view('emails.templateUserRegister')
                ->from($address, $name)                    
                ->subject($subject)
                ->with([ 'message' => $this->data['message'] ]);
```

Try this:

```
$message = $this->data['message'];
return $this->view('emails.templateUserRegister')
                ->from($address, $name)                    
                ->subject($subject)
                ->with('message', $message);
```

And make `$data` in

> app\Mail\SendgridEmail.php

`private` or `protected`.

If this doesn't work, try sending `$data` from controller as a string and not as an array. Remaining code will remain the same and this line would change:

```
->with([ 'message' => $this->data['message'] ]);
```

to:

```
->with('message', $this->data);
```

And you still need to change access of `$data` to `private` or `protected`.

**EDIT 2**

If you check Laravel's documentation for [mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail), it says this:

> Note: A $message variable is always passed to e-mail views, and allows
>   the inline embedding of attachments. So, it is best to avoid passing a
>   message variable in your view payload.

So to fix the issue, just change `$message` to some other name like `$data` or `$text`. Change this:

```
->with([ 'message' => $this->data['message'] ]);
```

to this:

```
->with( 'text', $this->data['message'] );
```

I hope this fixes the issue.

Comment: Sorry! the path is views/emails/templateUserRegister.blade.php in my code. corrected above

Comment: I did as you suggesed but still got same error message htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\resources\views\emails\templateUserRegister.blade.php)

Comment: Its working on local NOT in website using same username and password. it throws a error as 
=============================
Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials c69-v6sm9501842pfg.2 - gsmtp

Comment: Which hosting service are you using ? Is it 000webhostapp ?